# Not able to accept the response posted by server on my return URL in frappe framework

Tags: python-3.10, frappe, returnurl

I am trying to get the response on return URL, the response will be post by other server on my mention return URL. To catch the response I am using below code.

```
data = cgi.FieldStorage()
```

Its working properly when I am running it as python project on python 3.10. But when I am implementing the same logic in my frappe framework code which is also having python 3.10 its not working.
In browser under network tab I am able to see that the response is coming from server in payload on my return URL. But when I am trying to get it using cgi.FieldStorage(), its showing nothing after printing it.

Want to know is there any other way to do this.